# Using awk to find all words matching all patterns

Tags: bash, awk

Given an tab-delimited input like this:

```
us-west-2       vpc-abcdefg  42   elb-foo-bar-baz
us-east-1       foo     vpc-123455      eipalloc-bar
```

I want to use `awk` to do some pattern matching such that I can find all the words that matches `vpc-*`, `elb-*`, or `eipalloc-*` in the input. I also want `awk` to only read the input in one pass.

My outputs should be space-delimited matched values:

```
vpc-abcdef vpc-123455
elb-foo-bar-baz
eipalloc-bar
```

How would I go about it?

Comment: If you mean "starts with" `vpc-`, `elb-`, etc, then why not split on `-`.  What have you tried so far?  This is not a code writing service.

Comment: I don't see how split on `-` would help me.

Comment: You could use `split()` on `-` then test the first element.  I'm assuming that the patterns you specify are glob constructs - `awk` uses Extended Regular Expressions.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (where `gash.txt` is your input file):

```
awk -f - gash.txt << '__END__'
    BEGIN {
        tags["vpc"] = ""
        tags["elb"] = ""
        tags["eipalloc"] = ""
    }
    { for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) {
          n = split($i, a, "-")
          if (a[1] in tags)
              print $i
      }
    }

__END__
```

The associative array in the `BEGIN` block is probably an overkill, but it makes it easier to add more targets in the future.

EDIT:

I realised I was not producing the output in the same style as required, apologies.  Using that associative array it becomes fairly easy to modify:

```
awk -f - gash.txt << '__END__'
    BEGIN {
        tags["vpc"] = ""
        tags["elb"] = ""
        tags["eipalloc"] = ""
    }
    { for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) {
          n = split($i, a, /-/)
          if (a[1] in tags)
              tags[a[1]] = tags[a[1]] $i " "
      }
    }
    END {
        for (item in tags)
            print tags[item]
    }

__END__
```

Comment: Why would you tell awk to use stdin as the script file and then use a here doc to provide the script rather than just `awk 'script' gash.txt`? Also, that would incorrectly match if a field just contained "vpc" instead of "vpc-<something>" as the OP seems to want. You're also not using `n` so no point setting it and the 3rd arg for split() is a regexp, not a string, so you should use regexp, not string, delimiters: `split($i,a,/-/)`.

Comment: @EdMorton:  many people prefer to embed `awk` inside a bash script, for example the filename might be derived using `bash` (and `bash` is a tag for this question).  Having a separate file makes code management more difficult, which is the trade-off for the inefficiency of the here-doc.  I split on `-` so it won't pickup `vac<something>` if it is not followed by a hyphen (tested).  For a single character, the `/ /` are optional - they make no difference.

Comment: I'm not suggesting using a separate file for the script, I'm suggesting using the normal awk syntax of `awk 'script' file` instead of making it unnecessarily complicated with `awk -f - file << '__END__' script '__END__'`. I understand why you split that way but then your script as written can't distinguish between a field named `vpc` and one that starts with `vpc-` as desired (hint - you could use `n` to fix that). Using string delimiters for a regexp just doesn't make sense as it's a **regexp** so only use string delimiters when you have a purpose in mind, e.g. concatenating with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Might consider using `grep` with `-o` that will extract matches:

```
% grep -oE '(vpc|elb|eipalloc)-[^ ]*' data.txt
vpc-abcdefg
elb-foo-bar-baz
vpc-123455
eipalloc-bar
```

I know it doesn't give the exact output format, but it might be ok?

Comment: I thought about this approach too but I can't seem to get all the `vpc-*` matches on the same line, and so forth.

Comment: @StephenChu: `vac-*` is a glob construct, `grep` takes a regular expression (RE).  In RE terms `vpc-*` means "vpc followed by zero or more hyphens".  The `*` in RE qualifies the pattern or character to its left, which is not the same as in globbing.

Comment: I understand. I didn't want to confuse the problem solver to differentiate between `*` or `[a-z0-9]` as it wasn't my problem.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS='\t|\n' 'BEGIN{split("vpc- elb- eipalloc-",ks)} 
                          {for(k in ks) if($0~ks[k]) a[k]=a[k]?a[k] FS $0:$0}
                       END{for(k in a) print a[k]}' file

vpc-abcdefg vpc-123455
elb-foo-bar-baz
eipalloc-bar
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution as well.